# Using ng-click vs bind within link function of Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the link function, is there a more "Angular" way to bind a function to a click event?

Right now, I'm doing...

```
myApp.directive('clickme', function() {   
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.clickingCallback = function() {alert('clicked!')};
    element.bind('click', scope.clickingCallback);   
} });
```

Is this the Angular way of doing it or is it an ugly hack? Perhaps I shouldn't be so concerned, but I'm new to this framework and would like to know the "correct" way of doing things, especially as the framework moves forward.

Comment: Both are appropriate to do, you can go ahead and do whatever you see fit. The only difference in your example is that `bind` does to start a `digest` cycle; which might be something you might want as well, but be aware.

Comment: Umur, did you mean to say that `bind` does not start the digest cycle?

Comment: I use this when I need to avoid an expensive digest cycle, for example a large dataset that requires a user action. With the only difference being i use it in the link: function().

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You may use a controller in directive:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('appClick', function(){
     return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: true,
       template: '<button ng-click="click()">Click me</button> Clicked {{clicked}} times',
       controller: function($scope, $element){
         $scope.clicked = 0;
         $scope.click = function(){
           $scope.clicked++
         }
       }
     }
   });
```

[Demo on plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EAq92a)

More about directives in [Angular guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). And very helpfull for me was videos from official Angular blog post [About those directives](http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/11/about-those-directives.html).

Comment: I actually want to add the ng-click attribute to the element itself, not the template element (in your case, the button). Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out - I can use the "replace" option within the directive.

Comment: @Maxim Grach why not just put the button HTML in the HTML? It seems like a lot of work to display a button that calls a controller method and less obvious when viewing the HTML. PS I'm learning angular as well.

Comment: @turbo2oh this example is very simple and out of real life. But It shows how you can use angular directives.

Comment: @Maxim Grach I think that writing scope: {} would be more correct syntax-wise

Comment: @MaximGrach using scope: {} would isolate the scope, while using true allows shared scope.

Answer (score 36):

I think it is fine because I've seen many people doing this way.

If you are just defining the event handler within the directive,
you do not have to define it on the scope, though.
Following would be fine.

```
myApp.directive('clickme', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var clickingCallback = function() {
      alert('clicked!')
    };
    element.bind('click', clickingCallback);
  }
});
```

Comment: In clickingCallback, if you are changing any model/scope data, you'll want to call scope.$apply(), or put the contents of the method inside scope.$apply(function() { ...contents here...});

Answer (score 10):

Shouldn't it simply be:

```
<button ng-click="clickingCallback()">Click me<button>
```

Why do you want to write a new directive just to map your click event to a callback on your scope ? ng-click already does that for you.

Comment: I'm also curious about the opions on this one. `ng-click` versus `element.bind()`

Comment: Maybe just to make that part reusabel, repeatable the code elsewhere.

Comment: @Estevez that's exactly my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the controller in the directive and ng-click in the template html, as suggested previous responses. However, if you need to do DOM manipulation upon the event(click), such as on click of the button, you want to change the color of the button or so, then use the Link function and use the element to manipulate the dom.

If all you want to do is show some value on an HTML element or any such non-dom manipulative task, then you may not need a directive, and can directly use the controller.

Answer (score -3):

In this case, no need for a directive. This does the job :

```
<button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
  Increment
</button>
<span>
  count: {{count}}
</span>
```

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Answer (score -4):

```
myApp.directive("clickme",function(){
    return function(scope,element,attrs){
        element.bind("mousedown",function(){
             <<call the Controller function>>
              scope.loadEditfrm(attrs.edtbtn); 
        });
    };
});
```

this will act as onclick events on the attribute **clickme**